# How to Censor words in a Django Blog Comments?

Tags: python, django

I have applied a comment system to my blogs, and I wanted to apply a simple code to censor the bad words in the content.
I have a badwords.txt with all the bad words to be used as a dictionary to Censor the word.

My problem is I don’t know where I should apply this code?

2nd I wanted to know how to return the form as invalid due to the usage of the these word

Here is the bad words code

```
import fileinput

filename = input("Enter a file name: ")
censor = input("Enter the curse word that you want censored: ")

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    line = line.replace(censor, 'CENSORED')
    print(line, end='')
```

Here is the Django project I am working on
Here is the models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/post_detail.html"  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data()
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(
            post=post).order_by('-id')

        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None)
            if comment_form.is_valid():
                content = self.request.POST.get('content')
                comment_qs = None

                comment = Comment.objects.create(
                    post=post, user=self.request.user, content=content)
                comment.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect("blog/post_detail.html")
        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()

        context["comments"] = comments
        context["comment_form"] = comment_form
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        self.object.incrementViewCount()
        return res

class PostCommentCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.post = post
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post-detail', kwargs=dict(slug=self.kwargs['slug']))
```

Answer (score 3):

Django has a feature called [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#writing-validators) which you could use to ensure that a comment does not contain any censored words.

You probably want some list of censored words somewhere, which you could read from the file:

```py
with open("badwords.txt") as f:
    CENSORED_WORDS = f.readlines()
```

You can have a validator function like this:

```
import re

def validate_comment_text(text):
    words = set(re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split())
    if any(censored_word in words for censored_word in CENSORED_WORDS):
        raise ValidationError(f"{censored_word} is censored!")
```

In your `Comment` class you can use this validator:

```py
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text])
```

Comment: where do i place the validate_comment_text in the views.py or in the models.py

Comment: I would put it in models.py

Comment: I added the validators and everything before the Comment(models.Model) but didn't work. it is not showing any errors.

Comment: Just to confirm, you have also updated your `Comment` class to use the validator?

Comment: yes I did add `content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text])`

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try to open the .txt file (avoiding '\n'):

```
with open("bad_words.txt", "r") as file:
    CENSORED_WORDS=file.read().splitlines()
```

On the other hand, in my opinion it would be better replace the "bad words" for **** in the HTML files than avoiding the creation/editing of the text fieds.

take a look at this Django app

[django-profanity-filter](https://github.com/ReconCubed/django-profanity-filter)